# Python openpyxl blank cells conditional formating

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I have a problem with formating blank cells.
My code is

```
import setting_prices
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule
import os
from datetime import datetime


def load_file_apply_format():

    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = wb
    prices.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=today_as_str)
    ws = wb[today_as_str]

    redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111',
                              end_color='EE1111',
                              fill_type='solid')
    # whiteFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF',
    #                           end_color='FFFFFF',
    #                           fill_type='solid')


    ws.conditional_formatting.add('B2:H99',
                                      CellIsRule(operator='lessThan',
                                                 formula=['$I2'],
                                                 stopIfTrue=False, fill=redFill))
    

    writer.save()


prices = setting_prices.df

today_as_str = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), ' %d_%m_%y')
desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

filename = 'price_check.xlsx'


if os.path.exists(filename):
    load_file_apply_format()
else:
    prices.to_excel(filename, sheet_name=today_as_str)
    load_file_apply_format()
```

My formula works just fine, but excel treats blanks cells as 0 therefore they are always less than column I, and formats them. I would like to skip blank cells, or to format them to looks like regular cells.

I have tried almost all suggestions from the forum but seems like that I'm not able to fix it.

Please give me some suggestions.

@Greg answer for using :

```
   ws.conditional_formatting.add('B2:H99',
                                  CellIsRule(operator='between',
                                             formula=['1', '$I2'],
                                             stopIfTrue=False, fill=redFill))
```

results in formating cells which are == to 'I' column which I want to avoid. Also 'between' is setting format to all blank cells if cell in 'I' column is empty.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SEMs.png)

For example:
All cells for productA must be default formated because they are equal to cell in column 'I'.
For `productB` the only formatted cell must be `G3` because is lower then `I3`.
All cells for `productC` must be default formatted because cell in I is empty.

I thought that if I use my formatting code for lessThen, and another formula for blanks cells would do the work. But I was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to fix my issue with the try/error method.
I will post my solution here and hope that someone will find it usefull.
The final result is made by:

1. Placeing all cells from row to a list
2. Compare all values from the list with the desired one
3. IF the cell is lower -> apply formating

The final code is:

```
import ...



def apply_format_to_cell(cell):

    """
    Set background and font color For the current cell
    """

    ft = Font(color="FF0000")
    fill_black = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type="solid")

    cell.font = ft
    cell.fill = fill_black

    return cell


def open_existing_file(file_name):
    """
    open an existing file to format cell
    which is meeting a condition
    """

    wb = load_workbook(file_name)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = wb
    prices.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=today_as_str)
    ws = wb[today_as_str]

    for row in ws.iter_rows(2, ws.max_row, 2):
        """
        1st parameter says to start from 2 row 
        2nd parameter stands for -> till the last row with data. 
        3th parameter says start from 2 COLUMN. 
            In this case this is B2
        """
        cells_in_row = []  # making a list of cells which we will compare
        for cells in row:
            cells_in_row.append(cells)
        for cell in cells_in_row:
            if cell.value is not None and type(cell.value) is not str \
                    and cells_in_row[-1].value is not None and type(cells_in_row[-1].value) is not str:
                """
                Checks if the cell value is not Empty or str ( '' ).
                """

                if cell.value < cells_in_row[-1].value:
                    apply_format_to_cell(cell)
    if wb[f'{today_as_str + "1"}']:
        """
        For the first run only!
        Because: prices.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=today_as_str) will make again sheet
        with the same name -> Excel will put '1' at the end of name 'Sheet_name' > 'Sheet_name1'
        This if will delete this unwanted sheet!
        """
        del wb[f'{today_as_str + "1"}']

    writer.save()


prices = setting_prices.df  # import df with prices

today_as_str = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), ' %d_%m_%y')
desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

filename = 'price_check.xlsx'


if os.path.exists(filename):
    open_existing_file(filename)
else:
    prices.to_excel(filename, sheet_name=today_as_str)
    open_existing_file(filename)
```

Example of the final result:
[image: Final result example]